# expression must be a modifiable lvalue (for array)

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this program I'm working on, and one part of it is a linked list which I am working on making.  I got this far, but at this point in the code it tells me (on the 3rd to last line) that inst must be a modifiable lvalue.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    float color[3];
    float v[2*3];
    node *next;
};

class TriangleList {
    private: node *head;
    private: node * tail;

public: 
    TriangleList() {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }

    void add(float vertices[], float colors[]) {
        node *inst = new node;
        inst->v = vertices;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Below statement is not correct, as you can't do `inst->v = vertices` because by doing this you are trying to change the base address of `v`, read the error properly.

*error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘float*’ to ‘float [6]’*

```
inst->v = vertices;
```

you may want to do like below

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++) { /* len is the length of vertices */
       inst->v[i] = vertices[i];
}
```